# 2D vector specific element pass to a function

Tags: c++

I have created a 2D vector and inserted element accordingly for example

```
vector < vector<int> >  tube;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
   tube.push_back(vector<int> ());
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
       tube[i].push_back(j);

   }
}
```

Now I want to pass only row of vector to a function not the whole vector

```
void print(vector < vector<int> >  tube){

}


print (tube)//not like this
print (tube[0]) I want to pass first row of every element
print (tube[1]) or second row of every element.
```

Please help me how to do it.

Comment: That is not a 2D vector. It is a vector of vectors.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the first element of each vector you've pushed back in the vector of vector so far? (because row/column definition may vary according to how you think of it, so...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare something like this:

```
void print(const vector<int> &row){
     // print here contents of row, which is received as const reference

}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
print(tube[i]);
```

This way your *print()* function receives a reference to the row you want to print. The row is not copied, which helps save time and memory. The *const* keyword is guaranteeing that the *print()* function is not going to alter the contents of the vector; this makes it possible to call *print()* with *const* vectors as arguments, if you needed to.

Comment: Ok, the `const` reference is more efficient and expresses better the `const`-ness of `print`.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. However whenever I am printing tube[1], then its printing both the value of tube[0] and tube[1], 10 numbers at a glance. The code is below  void print(const vector<int> &tube){

  for (int i = 0; i < tube.size(); i++)

     cout << "tube[" << i << "]"   << " = " << tube[i] << endl;   

}

Comment: How are you calling *print()* here?

Comment: for (i=0;i<2;i++) print(tube[i])

Comment: Working perfectly for me. It prints 0-4 from tube [0], then 0-4 from tube[1], as expected from the code snippet *for (i=0;i<2;i++) print(tube[i])*

Comment: If you want to print only tube[1], then call *print(tube[1]);*

Comment: Ya if I call tube[1], then it print content of tube 0 as well as content of tube[1].

Comment: That's not what I get. When I call *print(tube[1]);* the output is "0,1,2,3,4". Tube[0] doesn't get printed. Can you post the code you're using, please? there must be something wrong

Comment: Oh Thanks. Now its working fine. Anyway I really appreciate your help.Actually I am working with multiple big file. This answer help me a lot.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped. Now please do the right thing and mark the question as answered.

Comment: How to do mark as answered? I am very new to this group.

Comment: Ya I got it and make it answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the signature of `print` to `void print( const vector< int > &row )`. However, conceptually you seem to be dealing with a matrix.

Comment: This would be inefficient, as you would be passing a copy of the vector. If the vector is large, this can waste lots of time and memory.

Comment: You are right, it provides the desired functionality, yet it is not the 'most correct' way to do it; changing my answer.